# Como validar la fecha de nacimiento

Tags: php, javascript

Amigos quisiera realizar la validacion de que si la fecha introducida es mayor a la actual, y al hacer eso aparezca un error diciendo (Seleccione una facha valida)
Gracias
Espero sus respuestas!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Si añades lo que has intentado es más fácil que alguien te ayude c:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con PHP:

```php
$fecha_de_prueba = '20/10/1976';

$time_ahora = time();
$time_entrado = strtotime(str_replace("/", '.',$fecha_de_prueba));

if($time_entrado > $time_ahora) {
  echo "Seleccione una fecha valida";
}
```

Con JS/HTML:

```html
<input type="date" id="fecha" value="fecha" />

<script>
document.getElementById('fecha').onChange = function(event) {
   var fecha_ahora = new Date();
   var fecha_entrada =  new Date(this.value);


   if($fecha_entrada > $fecha_ahora) {
      alert("Seleccione una fecha valida");

      event.preventDefault();
      this.focus();

      return false;
   }

   return true;
};
</script>
```